# how to restore deleted records in MDB

Tags: ms-access, database-restore

is it possible to restore deleted records in MDB?

Comment: Two words: time machine.

Comment: To whomever voted for ServerFault: how exactly does a question about a file-based desktop database engine belong on ServerFault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a near catastrophic loss of data in an MDB file once and I researched this a lot. I ended up purchasing a product named [Advanced Access Repair](http://www.repair-access.com/). The free trial allowed me to preview the data available for restore so I was sure that it was worth the $300 price tag.

I tried finding documentation on how to get the data back with code, but that didn't lead anywhere (for me at least).